# how to link libraries to your executable program in linux (Fedora)?

Tags: linux, dll, linker, libraries

I was trying to execute a library in my Fedora 19. The program gives this error:

```
./TestSoftware: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Therefore I checked whether I have these libraries and whether they are linked properly to my executable program using ldd and whereis commands and I got the following results:

#### ldd TestSoftware

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77f8000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x47596000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x47561000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf77c3000)
libcairo.so.2 => /lib/libcairo.so.2 (0xf768b000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x436d4000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x439b0000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x438f0000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x434fa000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x4368a000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x4354c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x434d7000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/libX11.so.6 (0x43721000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4396b000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x43316000)
libffi.so.6 => /lib/libffi.so.6 (0x43680000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x434f3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x438a6000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xf7665000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x43691000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x436b0000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x4750a000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf75b8000)
libEGL.so.1 => /lib/libEGL.so.1 (0xf7596000)
libpng15.so.15 => /lib/libpng15.so.15 (0xf7569000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf7565000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf755b000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x43a53000)
libXrender.so.1 => /lib/libXrender.so.1 (0x4392e000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/libXext.so.6 (0xf7547000)
libGL.so.1 => /lib/libGL.so.1 (0xf74cf000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf74c6000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x438c5000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x432f3000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib/libpcre.so.1 (0xf7460000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf7443000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf7440000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf743a000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0xf7432000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0xf742d000)
libgbm.so.1 => /lib/libgbm.so.1 (0xf7425000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/libwayland-client.so.0 (0xf741a000)
libwayland-server.so.0 => /lib/libwayland-server.so.0 (0xf740c000)
libglapi.so.0 => /lib/libglapi.so.0 (0xf73ce000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/libudev.so.1 (0xf73ba000)
libdrm.so.2 => /lib/libdrm.so.2 (0xf73ad000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/libXau.so.6 (0x4385d000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf73a9000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf73a3000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf738a000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf7383000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x47579000)
```

#### whereis libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

```
libgtk-x11-2.0.so: /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so
```

Now, I would like to link the library to my software, I tried exporting the PATH using

```
$PATHPATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64
export path
```

however, it didn't work

Comment: Can you show how you use the linker to link to that library? Also the compiler options might help

Comment: @Eric I got the executable file only, I don't have the source code unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x432f3000)
```

means that your binary is 32-bit (it would use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` if it were a 64-bit binary).

These:

```
libgtk-x11-2.0.so: /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so
```

are 64-bit libraries, and wouldn't do you any good. You need to install 32-bit versions of the missing libraries. On Fedora, `yum install gtk2.i686` should do it. See also [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-a-921435/).

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you are linking against the 64 bits version of the library while your program is 32 bits. This can be checked with the `file` command

There are multiple pitfalls here, but you need to use a 64 bits compiler with the appropriate switches or install libgtk 32 bits.

Comment: TestSoftware: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, BuildID[sha1]=0xe46c62af703c2a727d0fdadbd2b79ca7ce5ba083, not stripped

Comment: The result of #-uname -a is                                     Linux localhost.MyDslDomain 3.11.6-201.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Nov 2 14:09:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Yeah, this is probably your problem. You make a 32 bit executable and try to load it with the 64 bits libraries which won't work.

Comment: you can use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/32-bits/libs in front of your ./TestSoftware which will for the path inclusion. Or install the 32 bits version of the libs, but beware, it might mess up your install. Alternatively you can download the 32bits version of the lib and put them somewhere and include that somewhere to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH